# Doctrine generate entities command produces extra src/Gedmo files, which causes command stops working until folder removing

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine-extensions

I use Doctrine with [Gedmo extension](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions) in standalone noframework application.
Autoloading is done via composer, composer.json content:

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
      "App": "src"
    }
  },
  "require": {
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "^2.4"
  }
}
```

App core classes are placed in /src directory, composer files are placed in /vendor
Doctrine is configured via factory, its main code is below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Factory;

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\CachedReader;
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\CacheProvider;
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\FileCache;
use Doctrine\Common\EventManager;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriverChain;
use Doctrine\ORM\Configuration;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver;

class DoctrineFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @param ContainerInterface $c
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $c)
    {
        // Set up caches
        $cache = new FileCache('runtime/cache/doctrine');

        // Annotation reader
        $annotationReader = new AnnotationReader;
        $cachedAnnotationReader = new CachedReader($annotationReader, $cache);
        AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array(require 'vendor/autoload.php', 'loadClass'));

        // Add Gedmo extensions
        $driverChain = new MappingDriverChain();
        \Gedmo\DoctrineExtensions::registerAbstractMappingIntoDriverChainORM($driverChain, $cachedAnnotationReader);

        // Set up driver to read annotations from entities
        $annotationDriver = new AnnotationDriver($cachedAnnotationReader, 'src'));
        $driverChain->addDriver($annotationDriver, 'App\Entity');

        // General doctrine configuration
        $doctrineConfig = new Configuration;
        $doctrineConfig->setProxyDir(sys_get_temp_dir()));
        $doctrineConfig->setProxyNamespace('App\Entity\Proxy');
        $doctrineConfig->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(false);
        $doctrineConfig->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverChain);
        $doctrineConfig->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
        $doctrineConfig->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);

        // Event manager to hook extensions
        $evm = new EventManager();

        // Tree extension
        $treeListener = new \Gedmo\Tree\TreeListener;
        $treeListener->setAnnotationReader($cachedAnnotationReader);
        $evm->addEventSubscriber($treeListener);

        // Create EntityManager
        // $config['conn'] is connection credentials  
        return EntityManager::create($config['conn'], $doctrineConfig, $evm);
    }
}
```

My entity is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use \Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * Class ProductCategory2
 * @package App\Entity
 *
 * @Gedmo\Tree(type="nested")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gedmo\Tree\Entity\Repository\NestedTreeRepository")
 */
class ProductCategory2
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeLeft
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $lft;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeLevel
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $lvl;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeRight
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $rgt;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeRoot
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     * @var
     */
    private $root;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\TreeParent
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProductCategory2", inversedBy="children")
     */
    private $parent;
}
```

My cli-config.php is configured properly.
I run doctrine cli tool to generate entities boilerplate code via command:

> “vendor/bin/doctrine” orm:generate-entities src

It answers me:

> Processing entity 
>   “Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractPersonal\Translation”
>
> Processing entity 
>   “Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractTranslation”
>
> Processing entity “Gedmo\Loggable\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractLogEntry”
>
> Processing entity “Gedmo\Tree\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractClosure”
>
> Processing entity “App\Entity\ProductCategory2”

Entity’s working fine, but command adds extra files into my src folder:

```
src\Gedmo
├───Loggable
│   └───Entity
│       └───MappedSuperclass/AbstractLogEntry.php
├───Translatable
│   └───Entity
│       └───MappedSuperclass/AbstractTranslation.php
└───Tree
    └───Entity
        └───MappedSuperclass/AbstractClosure.php
```

If I generate entities one more time via aforementioned command, I get error.

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class
>   Gedmo\Loggable\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractLogEntry in
>   \src\Gedmo\Loggable\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractLogEntry.php
>   on line 9

To fix it, I need remove `<ROOT>/src/Gedmo` dir before.

May anybody help to find a bug in config to prevent this annoying extra files to be appeared?

Thank for help

Comment: clearing the cache did it for me :-|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added hack to clear annoying directory after doctrine generate-entities command. Complete listing of cli-config.php is below:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\ConsoleEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Event\ConsoleTerminateEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;

require "vendor/autoload.php";

/** @var ContainerInterface $container */
$container = require 'app/bootstrap.php';

$dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
// Post terminate cli command listener
$dispatcher->addListener(ConsoleEvents::TERMINATE, function(ConsoleTerminateEvent $event) {
    $commandName = $event->getCommand()->getName();
    switch($commandName) {
        case 'orm:generate-entities':
            // clear /src/Gedmo dir
            \App\Utils\FilesystemUtils::removeDir('src/Gedmo');
            break;
    }
});

// Create doctrine cli environment via helper
$helperSet = ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($container->get(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::class));

// Wrap it into Symfony Console App and add some extra commands
$app = new Application('Doctrine Command Line Interface', \Doctrine\ORM\Version::VERSION);
$app->setDispatcher($dispatcher);
$app->setCatchExceptions(true);
$app->setHelperSet($helperSet);
// add default commands
ConsoleRunner::addCommands($app);
// here you may add extra commadts via $app->add(..)
$app->run();
```

Official docs:

1. [How to wrap doctrine cli command into symfony console app](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/tools.html#adding-own-commands)
2. [How to inject event system into symfony console app](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/events.html)